# Unable to install @vue/cli

Tags: node.js, windows, vue.js, npm

My OS is windows 7 and node is 12.14.0 and npm is 6.13.4 .And when I am installing npm i @vue/cli -g with or without --bin-no-links I am getting the same following error stated in image. What's going wrong, please help.

```
C:\Users\dell>npm install -g @vue/cli
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\b7\c2\76
e1d8e353f98ab50b58e3c229f2621357d7a9690c95e0a48ff52b96bf68
npm ERR! errno -4070
npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, open 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\
index-v5\b7\c2\76e1d8e353f98ab50b58e3c229f2621357d7a9690c95e0a48ff52b96bf68'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-26T13_43_42_5
86Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
npm cache clean --force
```

to clean the cache and after that, to try again

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```